CancellationToken doesn't work on API request
I check a lot of tutorials and everywhere developers describe that if I add CancellationToken to my request then when the request become cancelled then flag IsCancellationRequested should change from fals to true. But be honest it doesn't work for me when I run it for .NET 7 & 8. Mabye someone tell me what I'm doing wrong becuase maybe I don't understand something.
Simple example bellow, when I test it via postman or Swagger and cancel it I have never got status 499.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/long-running-request", async (CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
    {
        var randomId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var results = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                return Results.StatusCode(499);

            await Task.Delay(1000);
            var result = $"{randomId} - Result {i}";
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            results.Add(result);
        }

        return Results.Ok(results);
    })
    .WithName("GetAllData")
    .WithOpenApi();


app.Run();


I try to figured out how can I cancel my API request and detect it to stop processing my logic in endpoint.

I don't see anything that attempts to cancel the request in the question. The way the code is written the only case cancellationToken is raised is if the application is shutting down. When that happens the code could reach return Results.StatusCode(499) but that response won't go anywhere because the application is already shutting down

and cancel it how? Do you mean cancel in Postman? That cancellation never reaches any server. What you did is cancel Postman's waiting for a response. No cancellation signal is sent to the HTTP server. HTTP, the protocol, has no cancellations. It's a stateless protocol so cancellations have no meaning. If the TCP connection is closed the server will notice after a while, but there's no way to say if that was a cancellation or not. After all, the client's mobile connection may be having problems

If you want to tell a remote server that a long running job should be cancelled you need to create an API for this. You'll also have to keep track of the long running jobs so you know which one to cancel. It's better to use a purpose-built library for all this, like Coravel, Hangfire or Quartz.NET

@PanagiotisKanavos It's not exactly stateless: the request itself has state. There is no inherent reason why a cancellation message couldn't have been implemented, it just hasn't been. Also in HTTP2 I would imagine you could close a stream rather than the whole connection, and the effect would be the same.

Your code is cancelling just fine for me, whether I close a Chrome tab or Cancel the request in Postman.
You can observe the cancellation by adding a log:
if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Request {randomId} was cancelled");
    return Results.StatusCode(499);
}

Note, however, that the 499 cannot ever be seen by the client. The HTTP protocol works as a single request and response over a given connection (e.g., TCP/IP). There's no actual "cancel" or "abort" command, so the way that these operations are implemented is that the application closes the connection. Once the connection is closed, of course, the client cannot receive the actual response.
ASP.NET will detect the connection being closed and will translate this into a CancellationToken for your code to respond to. Your code can abort its work (i.e., stop doing the loop), but any responses it sends won't actually make it to the client. Because the connection is gone.
